# Pandas Track Word Incidence By Date

Tags: python, matlab, pandas

I have a dataframe of word incidence in tweets as listed with the date of first tweet as the index:

```
                    Kill Counts Killing Counts  Murder Count    Violence Count
        2015-07-01  0   0   0   0
        2015-07-01  0   0   0   0
        2015-07-02  0   0   0   0
        2015-07-02  0   0   0   0
        2015-07-06  0   0   0   0
```

I want to compress all the duplicate days into one line and then plot the incidence of those words by day.

```
    df4 =df3.groupby([df3.index])
```

returns

```
    <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x180ba9510>
```

But the output seems to be a useless graph per day that none the less has several X axis ticks per day. I'm new to matlab plot, how do I group by date?

I got a chart of number of tweets per day to work with:

```
    df.groupby([df.index]).count().plot(kind='bar')
```

but

```
   df4 =df3.groupby([df3.index.date])
```

returns

```
   AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, I think this will work:

```
df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```

which will render

```
In [3]: df.groupby(df.index).sum()
Out[3]: 
            Kill Counts   Killing Counts    Murder Count      Violence Count
2015-07-01            0                0               0                   0
2015-07-02            0                0               0                   0
2015-07-06            0                0               0                   0
```

`count()` just counts the number of occurrences for each groupby row and does not really pay attention to what's in each cell, whereas `sum()` will sum the values in each cell for each groupby row.

No offense but your example is a little boring, because everything plots at zero, but here's what I get when I plot that groupby object (plotted with matplotlib with `.plot()` tacked on at the end of the above line of code-- I imagine the calls are similar in matlab):

[image]